# Latest Google Chrome & Opera stable not supporting XPAGES?

Tags: xpages

I have found errors occur on latest stable Google Chrome & Opera when I tried to refresh a simple XPAGES page from a new created NSF database

Here is the code :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
 <xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">   
   <xp:scriptBlock>
     <xp:this.value><![CDATA[XSP.addOnLoad(function(){
        console.log("hello world"); })]]>
     </xp:this.value>
   </xp:scriptBlock>
 </xp:view>
```

While I run the page for 1st time, no error occurs. But when I refresh the page, I have found 2 errors on Chrome's Inspect Element.

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'root' of undefined
 Uncaught ReferenceError: XSP is not defined
```

And those errors only occur on latest Chrome and Opera. I have tried to run that page on Opera 28, Firefox 43, IE 11 and no errors occurs.

How to solve this problem ?

Note : I use Domino / Notes Designer 9.0.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to a bug in Google Chrome 48. The issue is being tracked here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=570622.

The issue will be fixed in the upcoming Chrome 48.0.2564.103 version.

Comment: Google have released Chrome 48.0.2564.103. I already tested, that problem has been fixed